# jquery mobile refresh button not loading css

Tags: jquery, button, mobile, refresh

I have on my index.html file the header with the css files been inserted there.
Then I load a second page

```
<a href="page2.html">page2</a>
```

It works fine but when I click refresh button or access directly a subpage
then then the css is not loaded so do I have to insert the css and all the 
js files that I need on each page ?

Comment: Can you add the other html too? This is hard to get without the rest of the code.

Comment: in jquery mobile 
i suggest you to make all pages(data-role = page)
inside one page if that possible 
else you need to load all css java-scripts  inside ech page as you said

Answer (score 0):

You could to put the header in a file and then include it in the "html" pages (with a script language, for example php).

header.html:

```
<head>
link to your css and js files
</head>
```

index.php:

```
...
include_once('header.html');
...
```

page2.php:

```
...
include_once('header.html');
...
```